# How can I increase the size(length not width) of the input box?

Tags: html, css

```css
.textbox {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form action="">
    <ul id="formlist">
      <li>
        <label for="StudentName">Name</label>
        <input class="textbox" id="StudentName" name="StudentName" type="text" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="StudentEmail">Email</label>
        <input class="textbox" id="StudentEmail" type="email" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="StudentWebsite">Website</label>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" id="StudentWebsite" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="ImageLink">Image Link</label>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" id="ImageLink" /></li>
      <li>
        <label for="StudentGender">Gender</label>
        <table>
          <tr><input id="StudentGender" type="radio"> Male</tr>
          <tr><input type="radio" id="StudentGender"> Female</tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="StudentSkills">Skills</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="StudentSkills"> Java
        <input type="checkbox" id="StudentSkills"> HTML
        <input type="checkbox" id="StudentSkills"> CSS
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

How to change the length of the textbox? And also, is there any way to arrange the radio buttons vertically. Currently they are showing up side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use height:100px

```css
.textbox
{
    width: 350px;
    height:100px;
}

.radioGender{
height:25px;
width:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
<form action="">
<ul id="formlist">
<li>
<label for="StudentName">Name</label>
<input class="textbox" id="StudentName" name="StudentName" type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
<label for="StudentEmail">Email</label>
<input class="textbox" id="StudentEmail" type="email"/>
</li>
<li>
<label for="StudentWebsite">Website</label>
<input class="textbox" type="text" id="StudentWebsite"/>
</li>
<li>
<label for="ImageLink">Image Link</label>
<input class="textbox" type="text" id="ImageLink"/></li>
<li>
<label for="StudentGender">Gender</label>
<table>
<tr><input name="StudentGender" type="radio" class='radioGender'> Male</tr>
<tr><input type="radio" name="StudentGender" class='radioGender'> Female</tr>
</table>
</li>
<li>
<label for="StudentSkills">Skills</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="StudentSkills"> Java
<input type="checkbox" id="StudentSkills1"> HTML
<input type="checkbox" id="StudentSkills2"> CSS
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: And what about the Gender Radio Buttons?

Comment: snippet updated.  be sure that your id's are unique.  Two items CAN NOT HAVE the same id